# fwrite() is not a valid stream resource

Tags: php

I've created a class `Log` that write some content on file (*this allow me to debug my application in production*). Now this `Log` class is included into a `SingleTon` class called `Trace`, so for use the `Log` class method I simply do:

```
 Trace::getInstance()->info("Write some content.");
```

this is the `Trace` class:

```
<?php

require_once("Log.php");

class Trace
{
    private $_trace;
    private static $_instance;

    private function __construct()
    {
       $this->_trace = new Log();
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
       if(!isset(self::$_instance))
       {
          self::$_instance = new static;
       }
       return self::$_instance;
    }

}
```

in the `Log` class I have a `destruct` that destroys the read and write streams, like this:

```
if($this->_handle)
{
     fclose($this->_handle);
}
```

`$_handle` contains this: `Resource id #22`.
Now if I execute one call like this: `Trace::getInstance()->info("Write some content.");`, the system working well and the text is wrote correctly on the file, but, if I do this:

```
Trace::getInstance()->info("Write some content.");
Trace::getInstance()->info("Write some content2.");
```

I get this error:

> fwrite(): 22 is not a valid stream resource

I thought about an instance of class `Trace` that remained open so I tried with:

```
function __destruct()
{
    unset(self::$_instance);
}
```

for destroy the `Log` instance for each call. But I got this error:

> Attempt to unset static property Trace::$_instance in ...

I don't know what is wrong, someone could help me to figure out?

**UPDATE - Log Class**

For write on the `Log` class, I do this:

```
if(fwrite($this->_handle, $mex) === false)
```

where `$this->_handle` represents the resource like `stream` and `$mex` is the message to write. Now I fall in the Exception:

```
if(fwrite($this->_handle, $mex) === false)
{
    throw new RuntimeException("Can't write.");
}
```

only on the second attempts, for the first attempt I can write correctly on the file. In the destruct of log file I've:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    // Close the stream

    if($this->_handle)
    {
        fclose($this->_handle);
    }
}
```

If I use the `Log` class without static instance I've no problem, for example like this:

```
<?php

include "log.php";

      $log = new Log();

      $log->info("test");
      $log->error("test2");
...
```

no error happean.

Comment: `throw new RuntimeException('Can't write.');` is incorrect code.. should be `throw new RuntimeException('Can\'t write.');`

Comment: @noc2spamツ fix the typo in the example.

Comment: Do you have any sort of class hierarchy involving the `Trace` or `Log` class? Can you post a minimal working example reproducing the issue?

Comment: Seems that if I remove `fclose($this->_handle)` no errors displayed and all working good. Very strange.